# Animating specific location on an image

Tags: flutter, 2d, flame

My question is very messed up so i need the professional help to get more information and hints.

I am making a flutter app that has one page, on the middle of that page there will be an image of a building which has windows and i want to add shapes on these windows like ( light on effect(yellow colour), light off(black colour), image, button).
[image]
The positioned widget should be attached to the specific dimensions of the windows so if the user zoomed in the widget will change its size to fit the window.
I tried stack with image but it didn't work.
Should i create 2D model and use flame to make this work 
Or the flutter does not support this.
Waiting for your suggestions please

Comment: Your solution "stack with images" is good enough, you just need to wrap the `Stack` with  `InteractiveViewer`, more on `InteractiveViewer` [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zrn7V3bMJvg&vl=en)

Comment: Thanks mohammed for the help, i already tried the solution you provided but its not the result i am seeking, the stack can contain limited number of widgets before exceeding the boundaries.